# Spark-ThriftServer Blocks Spark SQL from Running

Tags: apache-spark, hive

The issue is happening in my local environment where I use docker compose to orchestrate hadoop, hive, spark, and airflow to run in different services/containers. I've dumbed down the setup [here](https://github.com/shinkou/dcas2h) so that you can easily run it and see for yourself.

The problem is that it seems the Spark ThriftServer is blocking things up so that no spark-sql or spark-shell can start. And as soon as I stop the service/container, things will return to normal.

So my question is, are we not supposed to run Spark ThriftServer alongside HiveServer2? Or is it simply a problem in the configurations that I overlooked somewhere?